# How many traffic Amazon Free Tier server can handle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to test How they work. I deploy 2 sites and want to get to know what is load balancing etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer service for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company/255746).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) enables you to gain free, hands-on experience with the AWS platform, products, and services. It is not intended to provide production-level services. However, if you can fit within the Free Tier, then that's great for you!

If your main goal is to remain **free**, please note that it only includes 15 GB of outbound Data Transfer. If your users are downloading large amounts of graphics, this might consume a lot of Data Transfer traffic.

It is **not possible to provide an estimate** of "how much traffic" an instance can handle. It depends on your application (blog vs video encoder?), the usage patterns and the types of information being processed. If all your users are all in the same location, the server(s) would be under a heavier load during the day, while if your users are **spread around the world**, the load would be spread more evenly throughout the day.

The only way to know how much traffic it can handle is to create a **simulation of normal traffic** and measure it on various sizes of servers. Or, just turn it on and monitor the amount of traffic that your users bring, watching the impact on CPU, disk and memory.

**Bottom line:** If you're just looking for something that's free, use what you can get from the free tier. If you want to provide a particular level of quality for your users, pay for the services that it requires.

Answer (score 0):

Amount of traffic an instance can handle depends upon what type of application you are running.
How much memory your each application instance is using. The same goes for CPU.
Also, free tier instance will have limited network capacity.

For e.g. Number of requests an video decoding application can handle will be much lesser than a web server.

Its always good to do a load test before going into production. Also, autoscaling is an option for you but you may exceed your free tier.

Comment: Using Ubuntu Server. Its a wordpress site with around 50mb+ sql, any rough estimate?

Comment: roughly 50-100 concurrent users if serving cached pages from wordpress.